# If $G / Z(G)$ nilpotent then G is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

> Let $G$ be a group. If $G / Z(G)$ nilpotent, then prove that $G$ is nilpotent.

The way I have worked out this question is fairly tedious, and I would be interested if there is a more straightforward approach here.

I solved this problem by showing that if $G / Z(G)$ is of nilpotence class $k$, then $G / Z(G) = Z_{k}(G / Z(G)) = Z_{k+1}(G) / Z(G)$, the latter equality shown using a tedious induction proof. Then the conclusion readily follows.

Is there a different approach to this problem, or is there a short way to prove that $Z_{k}(G / Z(G)) = Z_{k+1}(G) / Z(G)$?

Comment: I don't think so, and I don't think this way is particularly tedious or cumbersome. After all, $\;Z(G/Z(G))=Z_2(G)=$ the second non-trivial element in the upper central series of $\;G\;$ , and from here we go smoothly...I also can't see where induction kicks in: you have a *finite* upper central series for $\;G/Z(G)\;$ , and adding one element to it becomes an upper central series for $\;G\;$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: given a central series
$$
Z(G)/Z(G)\lhd H_1/Z(G)\lhd H_2/Z(G)\lhd \dots \lhd H_{k-1}/Z(G)\lhd H_k/Z(G)=G/Z(G)
$$
of $G/Z(G)$, then
$$
\{1\}\lhd Z(G)\lhd H_1\lhd H_2\lhd \dots \lhd H_{k-1}\lhd H_k=G,
$$
is a central series for $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of egreg's answer, you might consider proving (and using) the more general statement:

> A group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if, for every normal subgroup $H$, both $H$ and $G/H$ are nilpotent.

The argument is the one he suggested.

Comment: The sole downvoter might offer a word of criticism.

Comment: I believe you need that $H$ is central. Take $S_3$ and $A_3$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Using this Lemma 1:

> If $\pi:G \rightarrow K$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $\pi(\gamma_i(G)) = \gamma_i(K)$ for all $i$.

( Ask and comment me for the proof. )

By definition of nilpotent group we have:

$\gamma_{x+1}(G/Z(G)) = 1$.

Let $\pi:G \rightarrow G/Z(G)$ be the homomorphism. By Lemma 1:

$\pi(\gamma_{x+1}(G)) = \gamma_{x+1}(G/Z(G)) = 1$.

But $\pi(\gamma_{x+1}(G)) = 1$ means that $\gamma_{x+1}(G) \le ker \: \pi = Z(G)$. Thus:

$\gamma_{x+2}(G) = [\gamma_{x+1}(G), G] \le [Z(G), G] = 1$ because $\gamma_{x+1}(G) \le Z(G)$ and $[Z(G), G] = 1$.

As $\gamma_{x+2}(G) = 1 = \gamma_{c+1}(G)$, $G$ is nilpotent as required.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: Let $K=G/Z\left(G\right)$. There is the isomorphism $Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\cong Z_{n}\left(K\right)$.

Proof of Lemma:
Induct on the index $n$. It is obvious that $Z\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\cong 1$ so assume the induction hypothesis and consider the equality $Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z_{n}\left(G\right)=Z\left(G/Z_{n}\left(G\right)\right)$. For the left side,
\begin{align*}
    Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z_{n}\left(G\right)
    &\cong\left[Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]/\left[Z_{n}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]\\
    &=\left[Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]/Z_{n-1}\left(K\right)
\end{align*}
and, for the right side,
\begin{align*}
    Z\left(G/Z_{n}\left(G\right)\right)
    &\cong Z\left(\left[G/Z\left(G\right)\right]/\left[Z_{n}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]\right)\\
    &=Z\left(K/Z_{n-1}\left(K\right)\right)\\
    &=Z_{n}\left(K\right)/Z_{n-1}\left(K\right)
\end{align*}
which implies $Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\cong Z_{n}\left(K\right)$. Thus the result