# Does center contains commutator subgroup imply group is nilpotent?

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Assume that $G^{'}\leq Z(G)$. Show that G is nilpotent.

I show that if $G^{'}\leq Z(G)$ then $G/Z(G)$ is abelian
and in particular $G/G^{'}$ is the largest abelian quotient group of
$G$. but what I can do after this?

Comment: Use the fact that abelian groups are nilpotent.

Comment: What is your definition of a nilpotent group?

Answer (score 3):

As you know $G/Z(G)$ is abelian; in particular $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent. Now you can use the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626423/if-g-zg-nilpotent-then-g-is-nilpotent).

Comment: But why make the problem more difficult than it is already?

Answer (score 2):

Nilpotence is generally defined in terms of either the ascending or descending central series.

**Descending**: If $[G,G]$ is central in $G$ then what is the next term, $[[G,G],G]$?

**Ascending**: If $G/Z(G)$ is abelian then what is $Z(G/Z(G))$? Is it proper in $G/Z(G)$? So then what does it correspond to in $G$ (via lattice theorem)? So what's the next term in this series?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation*}
\gamma^3 G = [\gamma^2 G, G] = [G', G] \leq [Z(G), G] = 1
\end{equation*}