# If $G$ is nilpotent of class $c$, then $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent of class $c-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

*An Introduction to the Theory of Groups (page 117 question 5.36)*

> If $G$ is nilpotent of class $c$, then $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent of class $c-1$.

Since any quotient group of $G$ is nilpotent of class $\leq c$, so is $G/Z(G)$.

Suppose $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent of class $d$, by using correspondence theorem to construct a central series of $G$, we get that $G$ is nilpotent of class $\leq d+1$.

Combining these two facts, $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent of class $c$ or $c-1$.

So far I still can't get any contradiction if $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent of class $c$.

Also I would like to ask that is the converse of the result true? I think it is not. However I have tried some non-abelian groups of small order such as dihedral groups and quaternion groups but also do not give a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the length of the upper central series of $G$ is equal to its class $c$, and $Z(G)$ is the first term of that series, the length of the upper central series of $G/Z(G)$ is $c-1$, and so its class is $c-1$. The converse of the result holds by the same argument.

Comment: Just to make sure that I get your idea correctly: $1=Z_0< Z_1 < \dots < Z_c =G$. Then $\{Z_1\}=Z_1/Z_1 < \dots < Z_c/Z_1 = G/Z_1$. Since $Z_k/Z_1=Z_{k-1}(G/Z_1)$, so the result follows?

Comment: @AlanWang See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626423/if-g-zg-nilpotent-then-g-is-nilpotent), and other answers at MSE.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ya I do refer similar questions at MSE but none of them concern about the relationship between the nilpotency class of $G/Z(G)$ and $G$.

Comment: The other question more or less does answer your question, see egreg's answer.

Comment: Yes you have got my idea correctly.

Comment: @DietrichBurde what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: @DerekHolt Nothing is wrong, the answer is completely satisfying. I was just referring to the comment.

Comment: Is it ok to say that $Z(G)$ is the first term of the upper central series for $G/Z(G)$ even though the first term is really $\{Z(G)\}$?