# How to use the upper central series instead of the lower one in nilpotency proofs

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

I have recently been doing many exercises on nilpotent groups and I'm having a bit of a problem using the upper central series to prove theorems. I can prove them using the lower one just fine (mainly because of it's nice relation with the canonical projection), but I'd really like to explore alternatives.

I will show what I mean with the following example:

> If $H \leq Z(G)$ and $G/H$ is nilpotent, then $G$ is nilpotent

My original hunch is to use the upper central series, because it explicitly mentions the center of the group. In fact, this is the main suggestion I have seen on this site (namely, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626423/if-g-zg-nilpotent-then-g-is-nilpotent/626429) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241314/if-g-is-nilpotent-of-class-c-then-g-zg-is-nilpotent-of-class-c-1)). So let's give it a try:

If $\{1\} \unlhd N_1/H \unlhd N_2/H \unlhd$ ... $\unlhd N_k/H \unlhd G/H$ is the upper central series for $G/H$, then $$\frac{N_i/H}{N_{i-1}/H} = Z\left(\frac{G/H}{N_{i-1}/H}\right)$$

Now we define a series for $G$ as $\{1\} \unlhd H \unlhd N_1 \unlhd$ ... $\unlhd N_k \unlhd G$. Since $H \leq Z(G)$, we already have the first step in showing this is a central series.

From here, the only way I can see to proceed uses the Third Isomorphism Theorem: $$\frac{N_i}{N_{i-1}}\simeq \frac{N_i/H}{N_{i-1}/H} = Z\left(\frac{G/H}{N_{i-1}/H}\right) \simeq Z\left(\frac{G}{N_{i-1}}\right)$$

But this gives us an **isomorphism**, not an **equality**, and is thus not really what we need.

At this point, I get stuck, and end up just falling back on the lower central series.

Could anyone please explain a bit how to proceed, or how to use an argument that doesn't rely on the LCS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggestion: prove that the pullback of $Z(G/H)$ is contained in $Z_2(G)$; and inductively that the pullback of $Z_k(G/H)$ is contained in $Z_{k+1}(G)$. Conclude that if $Z_n(G/H)=G/H$, then $Z_{n+1}(G)=G$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin By pullback, do you mean $\pi^{-1}(Z_k(G/H))$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection? I’m not too familiar with the concept…

Comment: Yes; it's the exact same way you define the upper central series: $Z_k(G)$ is the elements of $G$ such that $Z_k(G)/Z_{k-1}(G)=Z(G/Z_{k-1}(G))$. So I'm saying: the subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $N/H = Z(G/H)$, etc.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I’ve bem attempting this for the past week, but I couldn’t get the inductive step to work… Could you please give me a further hint? The base case follows easily from $H \leq Z(G)$

Comment: Consider just the next step. Let $g$ be in the pullback of $Z_2(G/H)$. That means that $\overline{g}$ lies in $Z_2(G/H)$, and therefore that the image of $\overline{g}$ (and hence the image of $g$ under the composite projection) lies in $Z((G/H)/Z(G/H))$. But we already know the pullabck of $Z(G/H)$ lies in $Z_2(G)$, so the image of $g$ In $G/Z_2(G)$ must lie in its center (since $(G/H)/Z(G/H))$ projects onto $G/Z_2(G)$ )and hence $g$ lies in $Z_3(G)$. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thank you so much! Just what I needed to finish it off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First try to prove that for any normal series
$$1 = G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \dots \triangleleft G_n = G$$
we have $G_{i+1}/G_i \leq Z(G/G_i)$ **if and only if** $[G_{i+1}, G] \leq G_i$.

Applying the above in your case you have to show that $[N_{i+1}, G] \leq N_i$ for $i = 1,2,\dots, k-1$.